# Bash sort ignore first 5 lines

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, unix

I'm having trouble ignoring the first 5 lines of my file while sorting the rest. My current command sorts the entire file by the second item, however I need to skip the first 5 "header" lines. I need read it and write it to the same file.

Current Command

```
sort -f -t $ -k2n,2 -o /folder/File.txt /folder/File.txt
```

Example

```
2016/07/07 15:41:02
@24921
@
@
@-1
b$1$4$...
a$2$5$...
```

Comment: 1) Do NOT read and write to the same file. Use a temporary file and then rename 2) Use: `sort .. <(tail -n+6 /folder/File.txt) > /tmp/tmp.txt`

Comment: @SuperSaiyan The `-o` option is safe to use in this way; `sort` uses a temporary file to hold the output until the sort is complete, then moves it into place.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks! Learned something today..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sorts lines 6 and after of the file while leaving the first 5 lines unchanged:

```
{ head -n5 file.txt; tail -n+6 file.txt | sort -ft$ -k2n,2; } >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file.txt
```

#### tcsh

Unlike `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, `tcsh` does not support command grouping with `{...}`.  Instead try a subshell:

```
( head -n5 file.txt; tail -n+6 file.txt | sort -ft$ -k2n,2 ) >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file.txt
```

Comment: I realized I'm actually using tcsh. I'm getting Errors. "{ : Command not found." and "} : Command not found."

Comment: @AustinErck OK.  My guess for how to make it work with `tcsh` is in the updated answer.  (`tcsh` is considered archaic.  If you you are going to be doing more shell work and if you have a choice, see if you can get access to a more modern shell.)

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

1. Extract the first five lines and the rest into two separate files, `head.tmp` and `tail.tmp`.
2. Sort `tail.tmp` and concatenate `head.tmp` with the sorted result.

At the prompt:

```
$ sed -n -e '1,5w head.tmp' -e '6,$w tail.tmp' data.in
$ sort tail.tmp | cat head.tmp - >data.new
```